# jQuery class change not triggered in IE? Chrome/FF work as designed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

I've got a little jQuery script that should display a fixed nav menu once the page is scrolled below a 200px threshold and then change the class on each menu list item to "current" once that section hits the top of the viewport.

**The problem is the class change piece isn't working in IE (tested in IE11).  IE console isn't throwing any errors and it works as designed in Chrome/FF.**

The fadeIn/hide function works flawlessly across the board.  I've got another piece of script to switch out some content based on a click event and that's working across the board as well.

I've looked at some other questions with answers revolving around blur/focus in IE, but my comprehension level just isn't there yet.

It probably doesn't matter, but I have jQuery 1.11 hosted locally.

Am I overlooking something obvious or is this more involved?  Any help is so genuinely appreciated!

Rough working version of the site is at [www.4sdesignstudio.com/new-projects/bwh/index.html](http://www.4sdesignstudio.com/new-projects/bwh/index.html).

**Quick, abridged version of the HTML:**

```
<footer class="main-links">
            <ul>
            <li><a href="#main" class="scrolly button-row">Welcome</a></li>
            <li><a href="#main2" class="scrolly button-row">The Tasting Room</a></li>
            <li><a href="#main3" class="scrolly button-row">Tasting Menu</a><li>
            <li><a href="#main4" class="scrolly button-row">Upcoming Events</a><li>
            <li><a href="#main6" class="scrolly button-row">The Artwork</a><li>
            <li><a href="#main5" class="scrolly button-row">Current Wine Releases</a><li>
            <li><a href="#main7" class="scrolly button-row">Wine Club</a><li>
            <li><a href="#footer" class="scrolly button-row">Contact Us</a><li>
        </ul>                               
        </footer>


<section id="main" class="marker">
    A bunch of content
</section>

<section id="main2" class="marker">
    A bunch of content
</section>

<section id="main3" class="marker">
    A bunch of content
</section>

<!--  ...etc, etc -->
```

**The jQuery script:**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

// Cached variables to avoid multiple jQuery calls
var $mainLinks = $('.main-links');
var $headerLogo = $('.header-logo');
var $mainTastingMenu = $('#main-tasting-menu');
var $dessertTastingMenu = $('#dessert-tasting-menu');
var $menuSwitch_1 = $('#menu-switch1');
var $menuSwitch_2 = $('#menu-switch2');

// Plugins
$('.lightbox').nivoLightbox();
$('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane();
$('.scroll-pane2').jScrollPane();

// Event handlers

$menuSwitch_1.on('click', function(event) {
  $mainTastingMenu.toggle('show');
  $dessertTastingMenu.toggle('hide');
});

$menuSwitch_2.on('click', function(event) {        
  $mainTastingMenu.toggle('hide');
  $dessertTastingMenu.toggle('show');
});


$(window).on('scroll', function(event) {

if ($(this).scrollTop() > 200) {

  $mainLinks.fadeIn();
  $headerLogo.fadeIn();

} else {

  $mainLinks.hide();
  $headerLogo.hide();
}


var top = $(this).scrollTop(),
    idx = $('section.marker').sort(function (a, b) {
            return top - $(b).offset().top;
          }).first().index('section.marker'),
    el  = $('.main-links li a').eq(idx);

if (!el.hasClass('current')) {
    $('.main-links li a').removeClass('current');
    el.addClass('current');
}
});

});</script>
```

Comment: Have you tried putting in the `ul` part of the element chain? Like `$('.main-links ul li a')`

Comment: Your problem seems to lay somewhere in here: 
 idx = $('section.marker').sort(function (a, b) {
            return top - $(b).offset().top;
          }).first().index('section.marker'),
the idx is always 0 on IE

Comment: @ScottW - I have added the ul into the element chain with no luck.

Comment: @BirgitMartinelle - That makes some sense.  I notice when I scroll below the 200px threshold to fire the fadeIn, but before the first section.marker hits, it's applying the .current class change to the last list item - "contact" in this case.  Any ideas for a solution?

Comment: yes - see my answer below ;)

Comment: Have you tried `$('body, html').scrollTop() //...` instead of `$(this).scrollTop() //...`?

Comment: @chiliNUT - I get what you're saying and I think it's along the lines of where Birget is going, but ('body, html ') isn't working either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problematic code is right here:

```
var top = $(this).scrollTop(),
idx = $('section.marker').sort(function (a, b) {
        return top - $(b).offset().top;
      }).first().index('section.marker'),
el  = $('.main-links li a').eq(idx);
```

If you debug this in IE you will never get an index other than 0.

Even after playing with this for a while I couldn't quite understand your logic - so I decided to work up my own approach to determining the currently displayed div:
http://jsfiddle.net/6mkh2xme/3/

This has been tested on IE (windows, some ancient version), as well as Chrome and FF on a Mac.

Comment: Bare with me - I'm not good with jQuery and basically a complete novice.  The proposed solution doesn't work.  It switches the initial class change to the 4th list item ("upcoming events"), but isn't making the change from there.

Comment: can you update your site (the link you posted) with the change I suggested? It's easier to figure out & debug

Comment: Thanks for your patience.  I uploaded your change to [link](www.4sdesignstudio.com/new-projects/bwh/index-debug.html).

Comment: Thanks for the update. It actually made things worse :) as it broke the page on FF and Chrome ...
So - I couldn't figure out how your logic worked - hence: i came up with my own. http://jsfiddle.net/6mkh2xme/3/ 
I have tested this in IE on Windows as well as on Chrome and FF on Mac - this seems to work, hope this helps!

Comment: I see what you did there and that makes sense.  And yes, it fixes the IE idx issue.  Thank you so much!!!  For some reason though, the class change solution is breaking the jscrollpane plugin in Firefox.  I'm just digging into it now, but if you see something obvious, let me know.  I updated the index-debug.html link with the new code.

Comment: Your jscroll pane works on FF 31.00 on a Mac, but not on Windows ... it doesn't seem to be tied to the changes I made as it doesn't seem to work on the original page neither :| 
Please remember to remove the console.log statement in my code snippet :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61374/discussion-between-sforcash-and-birgit-martinelle).